# Converting times and calculating differences

Tags: c++

I am relatively new to SO so please correct me if I do something wrong here!

I just started a programming course in my university and we have a task where we need to convert two different times (in hours, minutes, seconds) and calculate it to see what the time spent was(this is like a running competition). I've tried to email my professor for help but the answer there was lacking in explaining how to actually do it.

For example: starting time is 17:10:10 and ending time is 18:20:20.

As for the different variables

- sek = seconds
- min = minutes
- tim = hours

Here is a code snippet for my take on it but whenever i run the build it gives me the time 0:69:70.

```
void tidsSkillnad(struct tid start, struct tid end, struct tid *difference){

if(end.sek > start.sek){
    --end.min;
    end.sek += 60;
}

difference->sek = end.sek - start.sek;

if(end.min > start.min){
    --end.tim;
    end.min += 60;
}


difference->min = end.min-start.min;
difference->tim = end.tim-start.tim;
```

Comment: One of the first things you should always do when programming math is to try out the math you intend to use with a pencil on paper. It finds mistakes really fast, and because you already have years of experience in simple math, you'll probably see what you did wrong right away and fix it. In general, don't any code unless you have a plan and that plan has passed a smell test.

Comment: On the Stack Overflow front, when you have code that doesn't work, back up your code and hack it down to remove everything that has nothing to do with the bug and make the smallest possible program you can write that demonstrates the problem. use [mre] as inspiration. You'll find that when you isolate a bug like this it is left with nowhere to hide and usually you'll have found the bug long before you reach that perfect minimum amount of code. If you don't, you have a perfect little example anyone can drop into their tools and see what you see (within reason).

Comment: I feel so stupid... Thank you so much for your tips, after that I quickly realized it! I guess my insecurities in the functions itself made me forget how to do simple math :)

Comment: changing `>` to `<` is probably enough to fix it

Comment: Yes, thank you Alan! I managed to solve it in another way but your tip would probably also solve it! Thank you for taking your time!